# MyBatis returns some columns as null, 0

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I am using MyBatis and Spring Boot. I am trying to extract data from the db using this:

```
    <select id="queryDeviceList" resultType="DeviceList">
        SELECT id, mac_address, is_active
        FROM ct_device_list dl
        where dl.is_active = 1
    </select>
```

and my POJO is

```
@Data
public class DeviceList {

    private int id;
    private String mac_address;
    private int is_active;
}
```

and my DAO is

```
    List <DeviceList> queryDeviceList();
```

and my table CT_DEVICE_LIST in Oracle db has

```
CREATE TABLE CT_DEVICE_LIST
 (
   ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL
 , MAC_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(17) NOT NULL
 , IS_ACTIVE NUMBER(1) NOT NULL
 , CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT CT_DEVICE_LIST_PK PRIMARY KEY
   (
     ID
   )
   ENABLE
 );
```

But the results I got is:

> id=1, mac_address=null, is_active = 0

but my mac_address has value and is_active is not 0 in the database.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set `mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true`, you should use

```java
@Data
public class DeviceList {

    private Integer id;
    private String macAddress;
    private Integer isActive;
}
```

Remember not to use primitive type `int`, if you don't want set default to 0.